# Change root chmod privileges to r—r—r—

Tags: shell, unix, chmod

The question is: if I change the privileges of the chmod program from rwxr-xr-x to r—r—r—, how can I undo it? I won’t have any rights to use chmod again

Comment: you gonna have to write a c program to call the chmod api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like said in this [topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83862/how-to-chmod-without-usr-bin-chmod).
you can use this folowing command :

```
/lib/ld-linux.so /bin/chmod +x /bin/chmod
```

or use `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` if you are on 64bits system

Comment: Thank you! Now I can use this problem as an exercise to give to my friends and be sure that we can undo all that))